# Why the renderers Renderer[] array are all null?

Tags: unity, c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LightsEffect : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<UnityEngine.GameObject> waypoints;
    public int howmanylight = 5;
    public Generatenumbers gn;
    public bool changeLightsDirection = false;
    public float delay = 0.1f;

    private List<UnityEngine.GameObject> objects;
    private Renderer[] renderers;
    private int greenIndex = 0;
    private float lastChangeTime;

    private void Start()
    {
        //waypoints = new List<UnityEngine.GameObject>();
        objects = new List<UnityEngine.GameObject>();

        if (howmanylight > 0)
        {
            UnityEngine.GameObject go1 = UnityEngine.GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Sphere);
            duplicateObject(go1, howmanylight);
            LightsEffects();
        }
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        LightsEffectCore();
    }

    public void duplicateObject(UnityEngine.GameObject original, int howmany)
    {
        howmany++;
        for (int i = 0; i < waypoints.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < howmany; j++)
            {
                Vector3 position = waypoints[i].transform.position + j * (waypoints[i + 1].transform.position - waypoints[i].transform.position) / howmany;
                UnityEngine.GameObject go = Instantiate(original, new Vector3(position.x, 0, position.z), Quaternion.identity);
                go.transform.localScale = new Vector3(0.3f, 0.1f, 0.3f);
                objects.Add(go);
            }
        }
    }

    private void LightsEffects()
    {
        renderers = new Renderer[objects.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
        {
            renderers[i] = objects[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
            renderers[i].material.color = Color.red;
        }

        // Set green color to the first one
        greenIndex = 0;
        renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
    }

    private void LightsEffectCore()
    {
        // Change color each `delay` seconds
        if (Time.time > lastChangeTime + delay)
        {
            lastChangeTime = Time.time;

            // Set color of the last renderer to red
            // and the color of the current one to green
            renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.red;
            if (changeLightsDirection == true)
            {
                Array.Reverse(renderers);
                changeLightsDirection = false;
            }
            greenIndex = (greenIndex + 1) % renderers.Length;
            renderers[greenIndex].material.color = Color.green;
        }
    }
}
```

In this line if for example objects count is 5 then there will be 5 renderers but they will be all null.

```
renderers = new Renderer[objects.Count];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`Renderer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer.html) is a [reference type](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types).

In C#, [creating an array](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays) of any reference type initializes all entries in that array to `null`. To give these newly-created entries other values, you have to do so explicitly.

Note that you appear to be trying to do so in the code that follows immediately after:

```
for (int i = 0; i < renderers.Length; i++)
{
    renderers[i] = objects[i].GetComponent<Renderer>();
    renderers[i].material.color = Color.red;
}
```

On the surface, this is correct and should result in `renderers` containing five non-null references *assuming* `GetComponent` is not itself returning null. If it is, your attempt to access `renderers[i].material` is going to throw an exception.

If that's the ultimate behavior you are seeing, you probably have a bug in that `objects[i]` doesn't have a `Renderer` component. It's probably not set up correctly or is not the object you expected, for example.

If you're not seeing a `NullReferenceException`, and you're just looking at `renderers` in the debugger immediately after the `new` but before you've executed that `for` loop, then everything is as it should be.